# Call a function from base class that uses the member functions of derived class

Tags: c++11, inheritance, visual-c++, member-functions

I've created a class and a derived class that are almost completely the same. 
The only difference is that the derived class has 2 different functions and 3 extra variables. I want the called function from class B to use the inherited function but with the PrivFunctions of class B. Instead when called, the function uses the PrivFunctions of his own class, class A.

```
class A
{
protected:
double x,y,z;
Function() {
*do something using the member variables of class A and the member functions of class A* }

private:
double PrivFunction() {
*take in member variables from A and return a certain value* }

double PrivFunction2() {
*take in member variables from A and return a certain value* }

class B : public A
{
private:
double a,b,c;

double PrivFunction() {
*take in member variables from A,B and return a certain value* }

double PrivFunction2() {
*take in member variables from A,B and return a certain value* }

main() {
B classb();
B.Function() 
}
```

I've thought about adding the addresses of the private functions in the Function() but that seems too far fetched. I feel like I'm missing something simple but I just can't find out how to do this neatly

Comment: I think you are looking for [`virtual` member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is declare the function in the base class as [`virtual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y01k918.aspx). This is a type of function that you define in the base class `A`, and then need to redefine in the sub-classes. Declaring functions as `virtual` ensures that the correct functions are being called and avoids ambiguity.

You code should look something like this:

```
class A
{
     protected:
     double x, y, z;
     //define as virtual
     virtual Function(){/*do something*/}

     /*
     rest of your code
     */
}
class B: public A
{
    private:
    double a, b, c

    public:
    //redefine your function in the subclass
    Function(){/*do something else*/}
    /*
    rest of your code
    */
}
int main()
{
    B classb();
    //This will now use B's Function
    classb.Function();
}
```